# Unrecognized field "ssl-required" (class org.keycloak.authorization.client.Configuration)

Tags: java, ssl, keycloak

trying to get a token from a Keycloak server with

```
 AuthzClient authzClient = AuthzClient.create();

 AccessTokenResponse response = authzClient.obtainAccessToken(userlogin.getUser(), userlogin.getPassword());
```

I get an error trying create the AuthzClient: Unrecognized field "ssl-required"

I am guessing it's reading the keycloak.json file and for some reason is not liking the "ssl-required" field. Any ways to fix this?

My keycloak.json file:

```
 {
   "realm": "SomeRealm",
   "auth-server-url": "https://keycloak.some.online/auth",
   "ssl-required": "none",
   "resource": "account",
   "credentials": {
   "secret": "some2355bdca-b140-4bc6-a3ad-8c4ca22abc"
 },
   "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
   "confidential-port": 0
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! Should have spotted it right away. I built the program with a different version of the Keycloak library than the Keycloak server. Important to make sure the versions match! :)

After making sure the versions match, the error goes away.